# MS SQL-SERVER Update missing fields using ref table

Tags: sql-server

I have an update statement that works but am sure there is a simpler more efficient way to do this. See below, any suggestions will be most welcome.
Basically there is a reference table that has missing data items to back fill the main table.

```
UPDATE a
set [fieldName1] = case when [fieldname2] = ref.fieldname2
                                    and left(a.[anotherfield],3) = 'abc'
                                    then ref.fieldnumber1   else a.[fieldname1]
                                    end
from table1 a
left join table2 ref on a.[fieldname2] = ref.fieldname2
and left(a.[anotherfield],3) = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are double checking the conditions with `case` expression ? you need `JOIN` instead :

```
UPDATE a
      SET a.[fieldName1] = ref.fieldnumber1 
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN 
     table2 ref 
     ON a.[fieldname2] = ref.fieldname2
WHERE LEFT(a.[anotherfield], 3) = 'abc';
```